# UNITY | Method return null (A: Order of execution)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im new to c# and Unity, can't solve this problem about 2 days.

I don't know why, but in `ItemOnGround` class on `Debug.Log` line always getting this error:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I tried use `FetchItemById` method, but it still wont work. Even if i just copy and paste everything from `Slot` class, it still wont work. I tried to attach it to different GameObject but it still wont work. Is it some thread problem or i do something wrong?

Thank you for any help

Here how scripts attached in Unity :  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i35eu.png)

So i have 3 `.cs`

`ItemDatabase`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using LitJson;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<Item> database = new List<Item>();
    private JsonData itemData;

    void Start()
    {
        SetLanguagePath();
        ConstructItemDatabase();
    }

    public void SetLanguagePath()
    {
        itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/en_Items.json"));
    }

    public Item FetchItemById(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.Count; i++)
        {
            if (database[i].Id == id)
            {
                return database[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Item FetchItemBySlug(string slug)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.Count; i++)
        {
            if(database[i].Slug == slug)
            {
                return database[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    void ConstructItemDatabase()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemData.Count; i++)
        {
            Item newItem = new Item();
            newItem.Id = (int)itemData[i]["id"];
            newItem.Title = itemData[i]["title"].ToString();
            newItem.Value = (int)itemData[i]["value"];
            newItem.Power = (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["power"];
            newItem.Defense = (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["defense"];
            newItem.Vitality = (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["vitality"];
            newItem.Description = itemData[i]["description"].ToString();
            newItem.Stackable = (bool)itemData[i]["stackable"];
            newItem.Type = itemData[i]["type"].ToString();
            newItem.Slug = itemData[i]["slug"].ToString();
            newItem.Sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Items/" + newItem.Slug);

            database.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int Defense { get; set; }
    public int Vitality { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Stackable { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public Sprite Sprite { get; set; }
}
```

`Slot`

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool hasItem = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        InitializeSlot();
    }

    void InitializeSlot()
    {
        if (hasItem)
        {
            ItemDatabase database = GameObject.Find("Inventory").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
            Item item = database.FetchItemById(0);

            Debug.Log(item.Slug);
        }
    }
}
```

`ItemOnGround`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemOnGround : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        InitializeItem();
    }

    void InitializeItem()
    {
        ItemDatabase database = GameObject.Find("Inventory").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        Item item = database.FetchItemBySlug("apple");

        Debug.Log(item.Slug);
    }
}
```

And `en_Items.json`

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Apple",
        "value": 1,
        "stats": {
            "power": 1,
            "defense": 1,
            "vitality": 10
        },
        "description": "Tasty apple",
        "stackable": true,
        "type": "food",
        "slug":  "apple"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Plum",
        "value": 1,
        "stats": {
            "power": 1,
            "defense": 1,
            "vitality": 10
        },
        "description": "Juicy plum",
        "stackable": true,
        "type": "food",
        "slug": "plum"
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Are you sure there is an active "Inventory" object in the scene where `ItemOnGround` is attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Engine has a specific [Order of Execution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

This defines the order at which Unity Callbacks are executed in every script.

For instance, all the `Awake()` callbacks in your MonoBehaviours will be executed before any `Start()` callback.

That said, it doesn't mean that it governs the order of execution of individual `Start()` callbacks from different behaviours.

In your example. It is possible that the `Start()` callback of the `ItemOnGround` behaviour is invoked before `ItemDatabase`'s. In which case, you're making calls to an `ItemDatabase` that hasn't been initialized yet. So here is what I suggest:

Approach 1:

Knowing that `Awake()` is called before `Start()` you could initialize your `ItemDatabase` by changing `Start()` to:

```
void Awake()
{
    SetLanguagePath();
    ConstructItemDatabase();
}
```

Approach 2:

You could adjust the [Script Execution Order settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html). in Edit > Project Settings.

This allows you to give a priority order to each of your MonoBehaviours.

By giving the script `ItemDatabase` a lower number (higher priority) than `ItemOnGround`'s, you're telling the engine to invoke `ItemDatabase.Start()` before `ItemOnGround.Start()`.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that. Now it works, thank you very much! <3